# Update the version of only one PrimeFaces component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I currently use PrimeFaces 7.0 in my project. There are some components in PrimeFaces 10 that are useful for my project.

However to update all the components of PrimeFaces is difficult due to many stylizations that contain in the project.

Is there any way to update just one component?

Example: I need to use the `<p:dataGrid>` of PrimeFaces 10. Is there any way to update only it in my project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running two versions of PrimeFaces within a project is not possible.

Consider upgrading, regardless styling issues you will need to overcome. Apart from many bug fixes, there are also security fixes! And there will be fixes in the future you can more easily migrate to if you bite the apple now.

And yes, you might be able to back port (changes to) single components, but that will be very laborious. I would not recommend that path.

Comment: I completely agree with everything stated here in this solution.